# Value not updating in class C++

Tags: c++, oop, variables

I'm writing an assignment program which implements OOP principle which is meant to simulate an election.

I have a class Party:

```
class Party{
public:
    Party(){};
    ~Party(){};
    Party(std::string name, int budget){partyName = name; electionBudget = budget;}
    std::string getPartyName(){return partyName;}
    std::string getLeaderName(){return leaderName;}
    std::string getManagerName(){return managerName;}

    int getElectionBudget(){return electionBudget;}
    void setElectionBudget(int budget){electionBudget = budget;}

    void setLeaderName(std::string lName){leaderName = lName;}
    void setManagerName(std::string mName){managerName = mName;}

    std::vector<Stance> getPartyStances(){return partyStance;}
    void setPartyStances(std::vector<Stance> pStance){partyStance = pStance;}

    void *leaderPtr;
    void *managerPtr;

    void setLeader(void *a){leaderPtr = a; }
    void setManager(void *a){managerPtr = a;}

    void spendMoneyOnEvent(int cost){
        int currentBudget = getElectionBudget();
        setElectionBudget(currentBudget - cost);
    }


    void print();

private:
    std::string partyName;
    std::string leaderName;
    std::string managerName;
    std::vector<Stance> partyStance;
    int electionBudget;
};
```

In a big for loop, every day I update the budget each party has left like this:

```
for(Party p : partiesVector){
            std::cout << p.getPartyName() << " budget remaining: " << "$" << p.getElectionBudget() << std::endl;
        }
```

I also have the code implemented in my main.cpp to update the budget every time an event happens. For example:

```
case 0:
        std::cout << debate.getEventName() << std::endl;
        std::cout << debate.getEventDecription() << std::endl;

        party1.spendMoneyOnEvent(500);

        std::cout << party1.debate.haveDebate(party1, party2, party3);
        break;
```

However, no matter what I try with setting of things or trying to update the variable, it always remains the same (what I declared it as). Is there something I'm not understanding or missing here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I'm still relatively new to C++

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for(Party p : partiesVector)` is receiving the `Party` object **by value**, thus a *copy* made. Any updates to `p` will update the copy, not the original.  Make sure such loops receive the `Party` **by reference** instead:

```cpp
for(Party &p : partiesVector)
```

You should do this anyway, even for read-only loops.

More importantly, your display loop is iteration through a `vector` of `Party` objects, but your update code is directly updating a `Party` object that is not in the `vector`. Likely you made another *copy* when you added the `Party` to the `vector`. So you should change your update code to refer to the `Party` in the `vector`.

```cpp
partiesVector[someIndex].spendMoneyOnEvent(500);
```

Or else change the `vector` to hold pointers to `Party` objects you have created external to the `vector`.

```cpp
vector<Party*> partiesVector;
...
Party party1;
...
partiesVector.push_back(&party1);
...
party1.spendMoneyOnEvent(500);
...
for(Party *p : partiesVector) {...}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for answering so thoroughly. I didn't know I was making a copy in C++ just thought I was accessing it

Comment: @DamonO'Neil C++ is based on value semantics, not reference semantics like in many other languages. If you want reference semantics in C++, you have to be explicit about it.